# Language based on HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE and database languages

Tags: php, multilingual

I have a web site made in 3 languages, but will (maybe) be expanded.
So I created a table on the database where I insert the languages of the Website.

As index.php I have a script. If the URI detected is "/" the script redirects to /language/index.php.

I'd like now to have a script which dinamically redirects based on HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE.
My problem is that, the following script I made works only with the first foreach run.

```
$abbr = $link->query("SELECT abbr AS langs FROM LANGS");
while($langs_db = mysqli_fetch_array($abbr)){
    $site_langs[] = $langs_db['langs'];
}

$client_lang = substr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'], 0, 2);

foreach($site_langs as $lang){
    switch($client_lang){
        case $client_lang == $lang:
            header("location: http://www.mysite.com/$lang/index.php");
        break;

        default:
            header("location: http://www.mysite.com/$lang/index.php");
        break;
    }
}
```

I thought a solution like:

```
case $client_lang == $lang:
    $find "location: http://www.mysite.com/$lang/index.php";
    break;

default:
    $not_find = "location: http://www.mysite.com/$lang/index.php";
    break;
```

And then:

```
  if($find != ''){
       header($find);
  }else{
       header(not_find);
  }
```

But I'm not sure this it's a good idea...

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
// Set the default language as a fall back
$default_lang='en';

// Have an array with all languages your site supports
$langs=array('en', 'es', 'pt', /* etc... */);

// Query the browser's first preferred language
$client_lang = substr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'], 0, 2);

// See if the language is supported otherwise redirect use the default one
$client_lang = (in_array($client_lang, $langs) ? $client_lang : $default_lang);
header("Location: /$client_lang/index.php");
```

Alternatively though you may want to consider gettext:

http://php.net/manual/en/book.gettext.php